# Saving pagination in Oracle Apex Interactive Report

Tags: javascript, oracle11g, pagination, oracle-apex

Recently I've come across the problem in Oracle Apex 4.2.0003 with saving pagination in Interactive Report. I have a page, in which there are two reports: the first one is Classic, and the second one is Interactive, at that they are working as "master-detail".
Besides, Interactive report has both data from a view and HTML-elements like icons with links to modal or pop-up windows. All in the page works fine except one thing: refreshing of it leads to resetting the pagination of "detail" Interactive report in spite of full refresh or partial (without resetting the Classic, "master" one).

I've tried to solve the problem with javascript: I've written some code, which got current pagination from page and saved it just before updating, and the updating itself went by means of function `gReport.navigate.paginate`. I could use this way, but it didn't take into account the cases when there were less rows than the count of them chosen in the Interactive Report panel (where also there are search bar etc.).
Another way of solving my problem I'm considering now is getting information about current row count per page from the view `APEX_APPLICATION_PAGE_IR_RPT`, but I don't know how to get not information from the column `interactive_report_id`, but from the one named `report_id`.

Of course, I have the way which leads through getting information by having session ID and the kind of view (which can be customized in Interactive Report panel), but I can't say I like it.

So I have the following question: how to make Interactive Report NOT to reset pagination in my case? Is it possible to make it easier than to get the information from APEX views?

Answer (score 2):

This is a question which pops up from time to time and this is still an issue in apex 5, being that there is no supported way to do this, even though all it requires is opening up the api a bit so we wouldn't need to hack it.
You can use `gReport.navigate.paginate` for sure, and I'd recommend to go with that. Mind though: it's unsupported by Oracle (as in: undocumented) and it does not work in apex 5 (the JS for IRs has been redone). However, even in apex 5 the methodology remains similar: just "hack" it.

I would NOT query views. You still need IDs from the report and communicate with the backend, and you'll create many more problems than you actually need.

Just figure out in javascript when there is pagination or not.

HTML in the IR when there are more rows than the allowed rows per page:

```
<td colspan="18" class="pagination" align="left">
  <span class="fielddata"> 1 - 15 of 1878 
    <a href="javascript:gReport.navigate.paginate('pgR_min_row=16max_rows=15rows_fetched=15')">
      <img src="/i/jtfunexe.gif" title="Next" alt="Next" align="absmiddle">
    </a>
  </span>
</td>
```

HTML when there are less or equal rows than amount allowed:

```
<td colspan="18" class="pagination" align="left"><span class="fielddata"> 1 - 1 of 1 </span></td>
```

So: you can check if there is an anchortag in there or not.
If yes: perform your 'paginate' function.
If not: do a refresh.

Comment: Thank you very much, @Tom, for your answer, but it helped me, unfortunately, only partially. I've changed some logic in my Javascript code, but it works fine, when one needs to reset pagination or there is a case of having a part of the query in the middle or in the beginning of it. To say about the case of a part of the query in the end of it, I have the following problem. (Excuse me, but the site tells me that I've written too much, so I have to coutinue in another answer.)

Comment: Let us have 8 rows in the view used in IR and the count of rows per page equals 5. I go to the "6 - 8" part of the query, and when the function of refreshing the is executed with mode of saving pagination, I get "1 - 3"! And I have this thing in spite of that function gReport.navigate.paginate _does_ receive parameters 6, 3 and 3 (min_row, max_row, rows_fetched).

So the question is: what should I do to have a _correctrly_ working workaround?

Comment: @PiggyInTheMirror Are you actually having issues with calling `paginate` over any other issue? I don't know what code you use to call this, and it's probably that. Performing the native refresh will reset to page one as per design, so it can't be that.

Comment: I don't remember pages in application I'm working on, in which `paginate` could be used. And my code is like this:

    function refreshList(resetPG){
      if(resetPG || anchorCount() == 0 || (anchorCount() == 1 && anchorSign() == '>'){
        $(#'my_report').trigger('apexrefresh');
      } else {
        var pagesArray = paginationText(); var min_row = pagesArray[0]; var rows_fetched = pagesArray[2] - min_row + 1; var max_row = rows_fetched;
      gReport.navigate.paginate('pgR_min_row=' + min_row + 'max_rows=' + max_row + 'rows_fetched=' + rows_fetched);
      }
    }

Comment: Oh, no, formatting didn't work in answer... @Tom, anchorCount() and anchorSign() are the functions which get current pagination and the signs of it (I mean '<' or '>'). And the functions which work after refreshing the IR report are only ones which deals with css.